# Real Time stamp in perl code

Tags: perl, timestamp

Here's my perl code snippet

```
if($line =~ m/^Warning: (.*)$/){
                $subStepValues = {
                    Warning => $1,
                    Warning_timeStamp => `date`,
                };
                push @{$subsSteps->{'subStepValues'}}, $subStepValues;
}
```

I am parsing the output of tail -f from a file to my perl code and i am really interested to get the actual on the go time stamp, currently some how executing `date` is not working 
any other better suggestion?

Comment: My understanding about this code is that it should assign different time stamp for inputs at different time but somehow i am getting the same time stamp across all values - really need help 

I tried with gmtime() function and even strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", localtime), nothing really worked.

Answer (score 2):

How about a nice ISO timestamp?

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);

if ($line =~ m/^Warning: (.*)$/)
{
    $subStepValues = {
      Warning => $1,
      Warning_timeStamp => strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", localtime),
    };
    push @{$subsSteps->{'subStepValues'}}, $subStepValues;
}
```

Here is a simple proof of concept from the command line using an empty file and running tail -f on it and then going to another terminal and appending a few lines to it in the manner `echo something >> log`

```
schumack@daddyo2 12-18T1:57:23 338> touch log
schumack@daddyo2 12-18T1:57:26 339> tail -f log | perl -lne 'BEGIN{use POSIX qw(strftime);}chomp; printf "%s -- %s\n", strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", localtime), $_;'
2015-12-18T01:57:40 -- hello
2015-12-18T01:57:46 -- line 2
2015-12-18T01:57:50 -- line 3
```

Comment: FYI you may be able to shorten that format string to `"%FT%T"`.  The `%F` option is not available on all platforms though.

Comment: @Ken Schumack  i am getting this below error 

Usage: POSIX::strftime(fmt, sec, min, hour, mday, mon, year, wday = -1, yday = -1, isdst = -1) at watcher_instance_8.pl line 229, <LOG_place.log> line 106.

Comment: Hi @Shantesh did you use localtime in the call to strftime()? localtime is actually a Perl function not a variable I made up. I maybe should have used `localtime()` to be clearer. E.g: `print strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", localtime)'` gives
2015-12-18T01:22:41
`print strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", junk)'` gives the error: 
Usage: POSIX::strftime(fmt, sec, min, hour, mday, mon, year, wday = -1, yday = -1, isdst = -1) at -e line 1.`